# Java, Add together a value of elements in a JList

Tags: java, jlist

I have a jList that contains elements with 3 parameters.
The elements are

```
Item(double code, String name, double price)
```

I am trying to get the total price for all elements in the list and display it in a text box. Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ListModel from the JList

```
ListModel model = instanceOfJList.getModel();
```

Iterate over the model elements...

```
double sum = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < model.size(); index++) {
    Item item = (Item)model.getElementAt(index);
    sum += item.getPrice();
}
// Display sum somewhere on the screen...
```

Comment: thank you very much, had a couple of issues with it when i tried it last night, but got it working today!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will probably have to iterate over the list and call something like getPrice() on every element to create the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Does your item class has getters for the price?

If yes you can iterate over your list and each time get the price and add it to a variable; call it totalSum.

At the end you should be able to display your totalSum in a text box.